# Can we fetch selenium test result Passed or failed in selenium Ide or selenium RC using API

Tags: selenium-ide

Actually I am executing my selenium test by reading test case data from excel.I wanted to fetch whether the test result is Passed or failed  after execution of my first test case and write it in front of test case then y second test case and write it in front of test case and so on .

Before execution of my test case excelsheet screenshoot
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2LNz.png

after execution of my test cases excelsheet screenshoot
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMivW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the results using `TestNG`. `TestNG` contains default listeners which reads if your test passed/failed/was skipped.

To set this data in excelsheet you need to create a class that `implements` from `ITestListener`

`public class ExcelListener implements ITestListener`

If you use any IDE, you should see a warning about need of creating unimplemented methods. Allow system to create them and you should see methods like

```
@Override
     public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
```

Then all you have to code is
1. Open excel file
2. Find the right column
3. Insert status

To do that I recommend using `Java Excel API`.

To read existing excelsheet you need to provide absolute path, workbook name and a sheetname. Here's my code for method `getExcel`

```
public void getExcel(String filePath, String sheetName, String fileName) throws BiffException, IOException {
         String absolutePath = filePath.concat("/").concat(fileName);
          file = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath));
          workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
          worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    }
```

After getting an excel file, you need to iterate through data.
You can provide exact column and row.

Hope it helps!

EDIT:

Place a listener like this

```
@Listeners(MyExcelListener.class)
public class MyTestClass {
}
```

Comment: Hi Rafal,I got one issue i used ListenerClass but even if my test fails it going into "onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) " everytime I am getting Test case passed, like if I am using selenium.isTextPresent(expectedResult), even if expected result is not present its going in "onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) " . What issue it is.

Comment: You need to place a listener for a `@Test` class like this:

     `@Listeners(ExcelListener.class)
     public class MyTestClass {

    }`

Check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but It didnt work Rafal,I added @Listeners(ListenerClass.class) public class Signup extends SeleneseTestCase { @BeforeClass public void setUp() throws Exception { , but before using Listeners annotation I was using testng.xml file so  Listeners annotation doesn't make any changes,Please provide some other solutions

Comment: This issue is far too big to answer in comments.

Please, create another quesion on stackoverflow

Comment: I created Post Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300800/even-if-testcase-failed-it-is-going-in-ontestsuccessitestresult-tr-method-of